# iMacros script for facebook auto-comment, I'm getting problems to start the script

Tags: javascript, facebook, comments, mozilla, imacros

I tried find in Google and other forums, but I did not succeed.
I want a simple script that post messages automatically in my own Facebook timeline like this > http://prntscr.com/bd7tjf

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#addComment_*>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#addComment_*>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="teste"
```

I'm getting this error when I start the script

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified, line 4 (Error code: -1001)
```

Can you help me please?
Have a nice day sir :D
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't do that. It will most likely break every day. And spamming Facebook is not a good idea

Comment: I know that will break every day, but I only still learning, I need try please, help!!(I want comment only in my own page, not spam other peoples)

Comment: Use the API. That is allowed and supported

Comment: Someone said for me use the API, but I believe that API system works only for groups, and I'm not focused to post in Groups like auto-poster. I only want comment in facebook timeline (http://prntscr.com/bd7tjf)

Comment: It is only allowed to use the API. So either you use it or you don't do it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "loop mode" version:

```
SET comment "Hello Facebook!"
SET msg1 EVAL("'{{comment}}'.substr(0,1);")
SET msg2 EVAL("'{{comment}}'.substr(1);")

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:UFIAddCommentInput*
WAIT SECONDS=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:addComment* EXTRACT=HTM
SET id EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/id=\\"(.*?)\\"/)[1];")

SET msgDiv "#{{id}}"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV" CHAR={{msg1}}
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS={{msg2}}
```

---

Try the work of the following macro:

```
SET comment "Hello Facebook!"
SET msg1 EVAL("'{{comment}}'.substr(0,1);")
SET msg2 EVAL("'{{comment}}'.substr(1);")

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="div[class^=UFIAddCommentInput]" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=1
SET msgDiv div[id^=addComment]
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV" CHAR={{msg1}}
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{msgDiv}}>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS={{msg2}}
```

Comment: It works fine, but sometimes I get this error when I'm trying load new comments from my page.
http://prntscr.com/bdxpw0

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, so can't fix it. Nevertheless taking into account randomness of the problem, I recommend adding a small pause before the line #13, e.g. `WAIT SECONDS=0.5` .

Comment: Try test it for 2 minutes and you will see whats happend :' [

Comment: Sometimes the messages out backwards

Comment: I suppose that the problem is likely to be fixed with using the JavaScript Scripting Interface. Feel free to contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and we'll find a certain solution together.